# 4 left join table and I have to get the min date as well as the creator of the mindate in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me on how to get the value of another column of the mindate?

I already display the mindate but whenever I also need display the 'Creator' column all the result is fetching, it doesn't fetch the mindate.

This is my query.

How will I display only the Min tr.Created?

```
create table Tickets (EffectiveId int, Created (datetime), IsMerged);
create table Transactions (ObjectId (varchar64), Created (datetime), Creator 
 (int),Type(varchar 20);
create table ObjectCustomFieldValues (ObjectId(int), Content(datetime));
create table Users (id (int) , Realname (varchar120); 



insert into Tickets values 
(549837, 2018-04-02 12:03:23, null);
(612302,2018-04-02 09:46:29, null );
(616982 , 2018-04-02 09:33:24, null);

insert into Transactions values
(549837,'2018-04-05 08:35:22','50','Correspond'),(549837,'2018-04-06 08:35:22','45',,'Correspond'),
(612302,'2018-04-06 01:02:22','12','Correspond'), (612302,'2018-04-08 
01:02:22','56', 'Comment'),(612302,'2018-04-10 01:02:22','700','Correspond');
(616982 , '2018-05-03 09:33:24', '10','Correspond');

insert into ObjectCustomFieldValues values
(549837,'2018-04-02 08:35:22');
(612302,'2018-04-02 01:02:22');
(616982,NULL);

insert into Users values
(50, 'Grover');
(45, 'Seb');
(12, 'Jane');
(56, 'Greg');
(700,'Emo');
(10, 'Kade');

#I should compute also the minutes respond from Ticket Created to 
Transaction Respond

select t.EffectiveId, t.Created As 'Ticket Created', o.Content,u.Realname 
tr.Created As 'Min Correspond',
,Case When o.Content IS NULL Then 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.Created,MIN(tr.Created)) < 0 THEN 0
ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.Created,MIN(o.Content)) END AS 'Computed 
Minutes'
from Tickets AS t
 LEFT JOIN Transactions tr ON tr.ObjectId = t.EffectiveId AND 
 tr.type='Correspond'
 LEFT JOIN ObjectCustomFieldValues o ON o.Objectid = a.EffectiveId
 where t.Ismerged IS NULL

+-------------+--------------------+---------------------+------------------
| EffectiveId | Ticket Created     | Content             |  Min Correspond   
+-------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------
|    549837   | 2018-04-02 12:03:23| 2018-04-02 08:35:22 |2018-04-05 08:35:22               
|    612302   | 2018-04-02 09:46:29| 2018-04-02 01:02:22 |2018-04-06 01:02:22  
|    616982   | 2018-04-02 09:33:24| NULL                |2018-05-03 09:33:24


+-----------+------------------+
| Realname  | Computed Minutes |
+-----------+------------------+
| Grover    | 12485            |
| Jane      | 557687           |
| Kade      | 668878           |
```

Assume that the Computed Minutes is the correct computation.

So, MIN(Created) AND Creator are on the same table but  MIN(created) is not working if I add the creator. Also, I need to use the case statement to compute the minutes

When Content is null value then the formula should be,

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.Created,tr.Created)
```

but if the Content has a value then

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.Created,o.Content)). 

But if the result of Computed Minutes is negative then it is 0
```

Thank you.

K.

Comment: With emphasis on the M of MCVE, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I agree with @Strawberry ... you need to at least show us some sample input and output data, along with what is wrong.  If you want to post in this format, then you need a tidy query, without visible bugs (I see them in multiple places).

Comment: So much mess in the query. If you want people to answer your question you might want to provide a cut-down query that allows readers to understand what you want without all the confusing cruft to hunt through

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's a t-shirt just waiting to be printed!

Comment: @karen can you please provide more information with clear writing.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that,  I thought I uploaded the output image. So here it is, From the table Transactions I have to display the mindate 'Ticket Created' with the 'Creator' but it is not working.

Comment: I already edit it. Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this where a sub query find the min date

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,TR,O,U;
create table T (EffectiveId int, Created datetime, IsMerged int);
create table Tr (ObjectId varchar(64), Created datetime, Creator int,Type varchar (20));
create table O (ObjectId int, Content datetime);
create table U (id int , Realname varchar(120)); 

insert into T values 
(549837, '2018-04-02 12:03:23', null),
(612302,'2018-04-02 09:46:29', null ),
(616982 , '2018-04-02 09:33:24', null);

insert into Tr values
(549837,'2018-04-05 08:35:22','50','Correspond'),(549837,'2018-04-06 08:35:22','45','Correspond'),
(612302,'2018-04-06 01:02:22','12','Correspond'), (612302,'2018-04-08 01:02:22','56', 'Comment'),
(612302,'2018-04-10 01:02:22','700','Correspond'),
(616982 , '2018-05-03 09:33:24', '10','Correspond');

insert into O values
(549837,'2018-04-02 08:35:22'),
(612302,'2018-04-02 01:02:22'),
(616982,NULL);

insert into U values
(50, 'Grover'),
(45, 'Seb'),
(12, 'Jane'),
(56, 'Greg'),
(700,'Emo'),
(10, 'Kade');

select t.EffectiveId, tr.CREATED, tr.creator, o.content,u.realname,
         TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.Created,tr.Created) minutes
from t
join tr on tr.objectid = t.EffectiveId
left join o on o.ObjectId = tr.ObjectId
left join u on u.id = tr.Creator
where tr.created = (select min(created) from tr where t.EffectiveId = tr.objectid)  ;
```

Result

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------+
| EffectiveId | CREATED             | creator | content             | realname | minutes |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------+
|      549837 | 2018-04-05 08:35:22 |      50 | 2018-04-02 08:35:22 | Grover   |    4111 |
|      612302 | 2018-04-06 01:02:22 |      12 | 2018-04-02 01:02:22 | Jane     |    5235 |
|      616982 | 2018-05-03 09:33:24 |      10 | NULL                | Kade     |   44640 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: 0 row(s) returned.

Comment: Works fine with my data. What does your data look like?